# Solving a maze with DFS vs "wall following"

Tags: depth-first-search, maze

Consider a problem where a "robot cleaner" is placed on a room modeled as a grid. Each cell in the grid can be empty or blocked and all accessible cells are connected, meaning, all empty cells will be **accessible** by the robot regardless of its starting position.

We are told that the robot cleaner can only take one of four actions:

- move forward
- turn left (90 degrees, without moving)
- turn right (90 degrees, without moving)
- clean the current cell in the grid

We are asked to design an algorithm for the robot to clean the **entire room**.

---

My question is: Can this problem be framed as a [**maze solving** problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm)? I mention this because a common strategy (if the maze is simply connected) for maze solving is to be a "wall follower" (e.g. always try right, or always try left), and I wonder if **wall following** would work here.

More generally, why would "wall following" be a good strategy for either problem? Isn't it **enough** to do **DFS** (with backtracking) *even* if we pick an **arbitrary** order of directions that are "left to explore" from each grid position? (or explore directions at a given position in **any** order?)

Answer (score 1):

Try it on some simple examples.  You'll quickly see why wall following is not sufficient.

Comment: Since this answer is flagged as "low-quality because of its length and content", the subject of that flagging action must be an automated process that cannot differentiate authors.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it should be posted as an answer IMO.

Comment: @6005, good point -- I'm not sure it's appropriate as answer either...